# Date format in web form

Tags: html, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i use a google script to send and get some informations in a web form.

The date is stored in a google sheet in this format: 10/06/2021

Trouble is when i retrived this same date in the web form the date appear in long format like this:

Thu Jun 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (heure avancée de l’Est)

Here a sample of my code to retrived information:

```
var data = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getLastRow(),33).getValues();

var csdList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
var numCSD = csdData[0];
var numero = +numCSD;

  var position = csdList.indexOf(numero);
   
  var csdData1 = [csdData];
  Logger.log(csdData1);

  ws.getRange(position+1,1,1,33).setValues(csdData1);
```

result of logger:

```
7 oct. 2021, 09:34:17   Infos   [[ID, demandeur, date, ordre1, ordre2, ordre3, trouble1, trouble2, trouble3, fifa1, fifa2, ecid1, ecid2, nomtech, idtech, client, tel, adresse, cell, facturation, emailclient, details, traite, achemine, nomexp, dateexp, contact, bire, ferme, dateferme, approuve, dateapprouve, avancement], [21001.0, vdsavfdv, Thu Jun 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2021, , , , , , , , , , null, , , test, 418-555-5555, 160 gtt, , , fdaFD@FEDF.COM, vfsdavfdvfdv, , , , , , 2659685.0, , Thu Jun 10 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2021, , , htrwhrth], [21002.0, graegareg, Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2021, , , , , , , , , , null, , , , , , , , , grfsagfdgfdsga, , , , , , , , , , , ], [21003.0, gefagdsafgscdagvfdsagb, Fri Jan 08 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2021, , , , , , , , , , null, , , , , , , , , grfaegfdsagfd, , , , , , , , , , , ], [21004.0, gfsadgfdsag, Wed Mar 10 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2021, , , , , , , , , , null, , , , , , , , , fdsafdsfdsf, , , , , , , , , , , ], [21005.0, fdsfdsfda, 10/15/2021, , , , , , , , , , null, , , , , , , , , fdwsfdsafgdsg, , , , , , , , , , , ], [21006.0, bvfdsabfdsbfdbds, Sun Jan 10 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2021, , , , , , , , , , null, , , , , , , , , bfdbdfbdfs, , , , , , , , , , , ]]
```

Google Sheet information

```
ID  demandeur   date    ordre1  ordre2  ordre3  trouble1    trouble2    trouble3    fifa1   fifa2   ecid1   ecid2   nomtech idtech  client  tel adresse cell    facturation emailclient details traite  achemine    nomexp  dateexp contact bire    ferme   dateferme   approuve    dateapprouve    avancement  Date String 
21001   vdsavfdv    10/06/2021                                      null            test    418-555-5555    160 gtt         fdaFD@FEDF.COM  vfsdavfdvfdv                        2659685     10/06/2021          htrwhrth
```

Anyone have an idea how to solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I can see the output it seems like the output that you are getting and the output of the following code will be same:-

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date)
```

In this case you can use various methods in order to get month number and day as well as year.

```
for year you can use date.getfullYaer()
for month you can use date.getMonth()+1
for day you can use date.getDate()
```